# Statically-typed languages with function types supporting keyword arguments?

Tags: types, type-systems, keyword-argument

Some languages, such as Python, support keyword arguments:

```py
def foo(a: int, b: int, c: int):
    return a + 2*b + 3*c

foo(a=1, c=2, b=3)
```

Python along with mypy could be considered a statically typed language. However, the type of `foo` is `Function[[int, int, int], int]`, which does not contain any information about keyword arguments. Given a value with that type, there is no type-safe way to call it with keyword arguments.

Are there any statically types languages that support first-class functions and keyword arguments, and that have function types rich enough to handle keyword arguments?

Comment: From https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Optional_parameters, it seems it is not "natively" supported in (most) statically typed languages if by native you mean support like Python or R.